# invalid use of non-static data member using indices of vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, deque

> error: ‘sortAgain’ declared as function returning a function
>
> bool sortAgain() (int e1, int e2) {
>
> error: ‘sortAgain’ was not declared in this scope
>
> sort( searchedFor.begin(), searchedFor.end(), sortAgain);

I'm absolutely clueless as to the cause of these errors the function sortAgain is defined right above the function the sort command is being called in, and I have no idea what the first error even means... And advice?

searchedFor is a vector containing integer values representing indices to objects in another vector. I'm trying to sort these indices but getting these two errors. Both functions are in a struct and the sortAgain function is above the other one.

```
//SORT BY TIME STAMP
bool sortAgain() (int e1, int e2) {
    if(allEntries[e1].timeStamp != allEntries[e2].timeStamp){
        return (allEntries[e1].timeStamp < allEntries[e2].timeStamp);
    }else if(allEntries[e1].categoryLower != allEntries[e2].categoryLower){
        return (allEntries[e1].categoryLower < allEntries[e2].categoryLower);
    }else{
        return (allEntries[e1].entryID > allEntries[e2].entryID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Showing us compilation errors without the corresponding code that produced the errors is useless. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you have too many parentheses on the first line

Answer (score 1):

```
bool sortAgain() (int e1, int e2)
```

should be

```
bool sortAgain(int e1, int e2)
```

btw I dont really understand what that function does, but it definitely does not sort anything. I would strongly suggest to give it a better name.

Comment: it was a comparator used for sorting but yeah, the function isn't sorting anything